Excel VBA macro can only save file to Sharepoint in debug mode
I have a piece of code that automates certain part of my work. I have installed it as a customised plugin so that running it is just one click in the Ribbon. However the code can only save file to Sharepoint if I'm running the macro manually in debug mode. If running it normally via the Ribbon it saves an empty file to Sharepoint which is not right. I have the below key codes if anyone can help me with it. It's quite a long one so I've omitted the part where the data format happens and the part where an automated email is being sent at the end.
Thanks,
code to format data on current excel sheet
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
NewBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
NewBook.Worksheets(1).Columns("A:Z").Columns.AutoFit

dateoutput = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")

savefolder = "https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/personal/mycompanyusername/Documents/foldernamehere/"
fullfilepath = savefolder & "DY Tracking " & dateoutput & ".xlsx"

NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=fullfilepath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

code to initialize the automated email
I've tried to change my path around but nothing seems to work and the save file online is always empty. However, upon running the macro codes in debug mode it will be able to save successfully on Sharepoint.

I think I might have found the cause. So I saved the macro as an add-in (.xlam filetype) so when it runs normally it works on the .xlam file that's empty except the macro, instead of on an actual excel file that I open. If that's the case how do I fix it?

Hey @Blackcat, could you give me a simple example? Many thanks,

You can try something like this:
Sub examp()

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    If .Show = -1 Then
        Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
        SourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy

        '  ......here is your code

    End If
End With

End Sub


or if it is a static workbook (already opened) then
Sub examp()

    Set SourceBook = Workbooks("Name-of-workbook.ext")
    SourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy

        '  ......here is your code


End Sub


Thanks mate this one works but I'm just wondering if there is another way without having to initiate the file open dialogue every time and hit cancel?

The second example is without file dialog, then you have to explicitely define the source workbook. The suspected issue that when you start it from a control not the active sheet is the source sheet and therefore the paste is empty.

Thanks mate I eventually got it to work by define explicitly the different workbooks. Much appreciated!
